# Groupby if at least one element is in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```py
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'id': ["car", "car", "bus", "plane", "plane", "plane"], 'value': [["ab","b"], ["b","ab"], ["ab","b"], ["cd","df"], ["d","cd"], ["df","df"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df
```

```py
     id      value
0   car     [ab, b]
1   car     [b, ab]
2   bus     [ab, b]
3   plane   [cd, df]
4   plane   [d, cd]
5   plane   [df, df]
```

I would like to group my ids if they have atleast one element from the value column in common. The desired output would look like this:

```py
     id  value
0   car [ab, b]
1   car [b, ab]
2   bus [ab, b]
```

```py
      id     value
0   plane   [cd, df]
1   plane   [d, cd]
```

```py
      id     value
0   plane   [cd, df]
1   plane   [df, df]
```

I tried using groupby, but the problem is that some ids should be included in mutliple data frames, like

```py
plane   [cd, df]
```

Comment: Do you always have 2 values in "value"?

Comment: no, this was just a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I provided an answer that should work with any number of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set operations:

```
keep = (df.explode('value').reset_index().groupby('value')['index'].agg(frozenset)
          .loc[lambda s: s.str.len()>1].unique()
       )

for idx in keep:
    print(df.loc[idx])
```

Output:

```
    id    value
0  car  [ab, b]
1  car  [b, ab]
2  bus  [ab, b]
      id     value
3  plane  [cd, df]
4  plane   [d, cd]
      id     value
3  plane  [cd, df]
5  plane  [df, df]
```

##### How it works

first get the matching indices per value

```
df.explode('value').reset_index().groupby('value')['index'].agg(frozenset)

value
ab    (0, 1, 2)
b     (0, 1, 2)
cd       (3, 4)
d           (4)
df       (3, 5)
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Remove duplicates, keep only groups of more than 1 member:

```
keep = (df.explode('value').reset_index().groupby('value')['index'].agg(frozenset)
          .loc[lambda s: s.str.len()>1].unique()
       )

[frozenset({0, 1, 2}), frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({3, 5})]
```

Finally, loop over the groups.

##### alternative syntax (same logic)

```
s = df['value'].explode()
keep = dict.fromkeys(frozenset(x) for x in s.index.groupby(s).values() if len(x)>1)

for idx in keep:
    print(df.loc[idx])
```